# okhttp get request return body is not as I expected

Tags: android, get, okhttp

I use okhttp to get text of certain url. 
url I try to get is

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/famhouse.appspot.com/o/branchname%2Ftextfile?alt=media&token=a58b07a4-ddee-4ece-8222-0854a6c2a713

as you can see, it only have body saying "Testtest"

I get response well and I logged response.body().toString() but it says

okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@e640919

What I expect to see on log is Testtest

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContext=this.getApplicationContext();
    checkPermission();
    OkHttpHandler okHttpHandler= new OkHttpHandler();
    okHttpHandler.execute("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/famhouse.appspot.com/o/branchname%2Ftextfile?alt=media&token=a58b07a4-ddee-4ece-8222-0854a6c2a713");





}

 public class OkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/famhouse.appspot.com/o/branchname%2Ftextfile?alt=media&token=a58b07a4-ddee-4ece-8222-0854a6c2a713").addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                } else {
                    Log.e("dialog","response is : "+response.body().toString());
                    Log.e("dialog","response is : "+response.code());
                }
                }
            });
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use response.body().string()